# How can organize the disordered columns using awk/sed?

Tags: command-line, sed, awk

I have 2 columns including some data like:

```
one      two
one two
one    two
```

How can we convert it to:

```
one two
one two
one two
```

Comment: In this special case without empty lines: `awk '$1=$1' file`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Awk - re-write the fields with the default (single space) output field separator:

```
$ awk '{NF+=0} 1' data
one two
one two
one two
```

Sed - substitute multiple spaces with single space:

```
$ sed 's/  */ /' data
one two
one two
one two
```

tr - squeeze (`-s`) spaces:

```
$ tr -s ' ' < data
one two
one two
one two
```

column:

```
$ column -t < data
one  two
one  two
one  two
```

rs (reshape) to two columns:

```
$ rs 0 2 < data
one  two
one  two
one  two
```

Comment: @msndm if you have additional requirements, please edit your question to include them

Comment: Often seen is `awk '{$1=$1} 1'` to rewrite the line.

Comment: @glennjackman indeed... that's what I always used to use, I think it was someone on U&L who suggested the alternate... dunno